# Usuário windows a partir do GoogleChrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Gostaria de conseguir o usuário logado no Windows a partir do browser GoogleChrome. A partir de várias pesquisas o ActiveXObject consegue essa informação mas é um objeto que funciona exclusivamente no InternetExplorer.

Sei que pode ter problemas com falhas de segurança mas gostaria de saber se mesmo com todas as desvantagens existe algum meio de consegui-lo no GoogleChrome.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode listar com **window.navigator** todas as propriedades pra isso(algumas abaixo):

```
appCodeName: "Mozilla"
appName: "Netscape"
appVersion: "5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36"
language: "en-US"
platform: "MacIntel"
PluginArrayproduct: "Gecko"
productSub: "20030107"
userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36"
vendor: "Google Inc."
```